# I made a website without a <!DOCTYPE> what should I do?

Tags: css, doctype

I've been working on a website for about a month now and everything was going well until today, when I added `<!DOCTYPE html>` to my code, doing which messed up a lot of my css. Although I was able to fix most of it on the one page I was working on, I don't really want to go back to all the pages I already finished and mess with their css. Can I just leave my site without the `<!doctype>` ? If I do, will it affect SEO?

Comment: actually it's `<!DOCTYPE html>` (you're just missing an `|` over the `.`)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan did you understand the question ? cause i need someone to explain the issue to me .

Comment: You need to describe what issues you have exactly. What you have instead of `<!DOCTYPE html>` etc etc. Also, take a Goog at **Quirks Mode**

Comment: I put a . instead of a ! so it wouldn't disappear. I have nothing instead of <!DOCTYPE html> my html starts with <html> I know about quirks mode, i fixed most issues in chrome.. i get that unspecific questions are a bad thing here, i just want to know if its alright to leave my website without the doctype tag/in quirks mode. and if that affects SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `<!DOCTYPE html>` some browsers will render your website in quirks mode. To have a consistent look across all web browsers it is important to use the DOCTYPE. It's best to put the DOCTYPE in and fix up your CSS to correspond with standards mode.

Comment: Since I was working without DOCTYPE the whole time, I made it consistent with all major browsers in quirks mode, thats why im wondering if Doctype is necessary, if my website works good without it as it is..

Comment: You still have a better chance of guaranteeing consistency with all browsers using DOCTYPE. Also, learning now how to properly code in standards mode, while may be a bit of a hassle to fix, will help you much more building future sites and making updates.

Comment: Yeah, thats probably what ill do, thanks